# Забыли пароли от виртуальной машины в linux, какие стандартные пароли используются для root?

Tags: linux

Забыли пароли от виртуальной машины в linux, какие стандартные пароли используются для root?

Comment: А кто забыл? 3 символа

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/484088/

Comment: `init=/bin/sh`, например.

Comment: А кто вам сказал что на руте в убунте по умолчанию вообще есть пароль ? Есть кейсы где надо ставить руту пароль через sudo passwd root от пользователя который есть в судо

Comment: Либо перебор по словарю, либо письмо хостеру с просьбой о сбросе, либо грузишься с livecd любого линукса и правишь `/etc/shadow-`.